# How do I hide navigation and show it when I change the screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The page has a `header` to hide, that is, the `desktop` should show all the menus, and on the `mobile` to hide and call only through `burger`, with this problem is not, this problem solved.

But how to make sure that when the table or when the screen is reduced, only some blocks disappear and are called through `burger`, it is important that this is without duplication. How can this be done, is there any example?

Was there a `bootstrap for navbar that could be used to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: show your code pls

Comment: You can make use of display utilities: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/